# How do I "shift" the position of h1 tag when using before pseudo element?

Tags: html, css

I want to display an image on the left side of each `h1` element. I'm trying to use the `before` pseudo element for that.

The problem is that since there is no content, the `before` pseudo element is getting displayed on top of the `h1` element. How do I "shift" the h1 element so that it always appears next to the `before` pseudo element?

Here is the pen: https://codepen.io/saifalfalah/pen/qzRMjj

If there is a better approach to this, instead of using the pseudo elements?

Comment: why pseudo element? give padding to h1 and add a background-image in the area created by the padding

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in the question. Links rot.

Comment: keep inline-block, remove position and if necessary reset vertical-align https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XLpPYN

Comment: @G-Cyr it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get rid of `position: absolute` and use `display: inline-block` and probably a small right margin.

```
h1::before {
  content: "";
  background: url("http://lorempixel.com/40/40/");
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I personally prefer this over flexbox as it only affects the pseudo-element, not the H1.

Comment: @evolutionxbox same